# How to pause and resume in pyttsx3?

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I am making a pdf reader and am using pyttsx3 for TTS. But i want it to have a "play and pause" like feature but i wasn't able to do this with pyttsx3.I have tried to take the location of where it stops,when "pause" button is clicked by the user, by using the `Start_word()` event(because it throws the name,location and length of the current word being synthesized) but then i can't start or "resume" from that point because `startLoop()` starts from the begining.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always use something other than `pyttsx`...

Comment: You could also convert it to an audio file then play the audio file with something like `pygame`...

Comment: ok,....like then,i can catch at what length of the audio it stoped and start from there during "resume".Thanks,am gonna try it!.

Comment: No problem! Hope it works...

Comment: Was it ever found to be possible to convert the pyttsx engine to an mp3 file?

Or is the best solution still at: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/7#issuecomment-363887284 ?